# How to Change Battery/Network Icon in Android with Root or Without Root?

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, root

I am using Android Studio

I want to create a simple App or "Xposed Module", whatever would be working correctly

What I want is, on Launching the App, a List of different custom icons would be shown, select any one icon, would change battery icon to that selected icon.

Similarly with "Network Icon" a different list will be there.

So, how to change battery/network icon on ListItem_Selected

I want to know the code?

Comment: _"I want to know the code ?"_ SO isn't going to give you the code, that isn't what we are here for, show us what you have tried.

Comment: @Epodax Don't know where to start from buddy, I mean, I have created listview which is working, now on selecting a particular value how can I change the battery icon, I mean i don't know where to start from, how to do that ? Just give some help pal ?